# How to create and set content type in Vcard generate file in PHP

Tags: vcf-vcard

I have been working to generate vcard file in php just simple way.
my code like following :

```
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard;charset=utf-8;');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename= "'.$file.'"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

and generated file is something like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:Elke Schöne;
ADR;INTL;HOME:;;;Leipziger Straße 3;Markranstädt;04420;
EMAIL;INTERNET:praxis.elkeschoene@t-online.de
TEL;FAX;HOME:+49 34205 83980
TEL;HOME:+49 34205 88249
URL;WORK:www.praxis-schoene.de
REV:20161207
END:VCARD
```

But when i open this file in Windows Contact then name "Schöne" is not encoded and display with special character, but it works fine in Thunderbird contact.
can anybody help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can add the charset:
FN;CHARSET=Windows-1252:Elke Schöne

The semi colon at the end of the lines is not needed on vcard.